# Как создать опрятный проект на js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Рассматриваю пока только js, так-как даже с ним не справляюсь.

- projName
- src // папка с проектом которая должна отправится на сервер
- bower_components // папка с библиотеками
- tests // папка для тестов

И вот с этого момента начинается беспорядок, так-как нужен gulp и наверно ещё много всего, о чем мне пока не известно... И вот ещё какой момент, все библиотеки находятся в папке bower и это удобно и опрятно, но ведь пути для подключения их должны быть прописаны в приложении так, как будто они в корне лежат (это мне так почему-то кажется), а это значит, что УЖЕ не в папке bower, а это в свою очередь означает, что аккуратность теряется...

Вот и хочется спросить у тех, кто это уже прошел - как быть?

**Дополнение:**

Все проекты, которые я смог найти по запросу "angular proj" были либо слабые ( очень простые для примера ), либо папка bower была прям в корне. А bower в корне ведь не айс, он же качает и min и нет, да и в нем же ещё библиотеки для тестов и прочего, которые в релизе не нужны...

И можете немного раскрыть Ваш ответ ( Вы же знаете, что я только начал вэб постигать ).

***И отдельным пунктом прошу рассказать, как должен выглядеть проект передаваемый заказчику.
Должна ли конечная папка ( release ) соответствовать структуре, которая является конечной и её сразу можно заливать на сервер?***

**И у меня ещё один маленький вопрос - angular нужно как-то компилировать? Не могу найти почитать об этом...**

Начал создавать проект с нуля и пока вот как он выглядит, надеюсь с Вашей помощью он будет более правильный -

[image]

**Дополнение:**

Yeoman кто-то ещё использует в своих проектах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так конфиг пишите и когда сборку делаете собираете из bower типа вот так, например:

```
vendor_files: {
 js: [
  'vendor/angular/angular.js'
 ],
 css: [
  'vendor/чето-там/app.css'
 ]
 };
```

А свое приложение собирайте рекурсивно.

Вообще, для примера, возьмите какой-нибудь проект большой на github. Для angular перед минификатором не забудьте поставить ngmin, он переделает все объявления контроллеров директив и пр. чтобы можно было минифицировать.

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо! Но не могли бы Вы немного подробней.. ( я в вопросе дописал )

Comment: я собираю с grunt , делал на базе ng-boilerplate (переделывал под себя немного) сейчас я вижу что они на gulp тоже перешли у них структура такая, что bin отдельно складывается - это слитый и минифицированный проект.

Comment: "Они", это Вы про Yo? Вы его используете?

Comment: я про ngBoilerplate раньше он на grunt был, теперь на gulp